# Cant get data out of a blood glucose sensor using BLE on Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

> On receiving services the following function tries to connect to a service

```
@Override
public void uiAvailableServices(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, List<BluetoothGattService> services) {
     BluetoothGattCharacteristic c;
     BluetoothGattDescriptor d;


     c = gatt.getService(ForaBgGATTUUIDs.Service.SERVICE_SENSORS).getCharacteristic(ForaBgGATTUUIDs.Characteristic.CHARACTERISTIC_DATA);

     byte[] data = new byte[]{0x26};
     mBleWrapper.writeDataToCharacteristic(c, data);
     mBleWrapper.setNotificationForCharacteristic(c,true);
     mBleWrapper.requestCharacteristicValue(c);

 }
```

> Write Data To Characteristic

```
  public void writeDataToCharacteristic(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, final byte[] dataToWrite) {

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null || ch == null) {
      return;
    }

    // first set it locally....
    ch.setValue(dataToWrite);
    // ... and then "commit" changes to the peripheral
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(ch);
  }
```

> Enables notification for descriptor

```
 public void setNotificationForCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, boolean enabled) {
  if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
 return;
 }

  boolean success = mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(ch, enabled);
  if(!success) {
   Log.e("------", "Seting proper notification status for characteristic failed!");
  }

  // This is also sometimes required (e.g. for heart rate monitors) to enable notifications/indications
  // see: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml
  BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = ch.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
  if(descriptor != null) {
   byte[] val = enabled ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE;
   descriptor.setValue(val);
   mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
  }
}
```

> Request data

```
public void requestCharacteristicValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch) {
Log.d(TAG, "requestCharacteristicValue");
  if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
return;
}

mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(ch);

  // new value available will be notified in Callback Object
}
```

> What I expect is that it will send me the results after doing the above in a callback function but in the callback function it usually tells me that the Characteristic have been successfully written.

Comment: What you are getting

Comment: Do you get an error or something ?

Comment: I am expecting it to return values in call back but doesn't

Comment: Any help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: @Nabeel.Shaikh Were you able to implement this?